# Low Pass Filter using FFT up to the Nth overtone

Tags: complex-numbers, fast-fourier-transform

I'm writing a program in c# that uses Meta.Numerics to calculate the FFT of a signal recorded during one cycle. The overtones are presented as complex numbers. Now I would like to reconstruct the signal but only using the first $N$th overtones. One way of doing this is to calculate the amplitude and phase of each complex numbers (overtones) and make a sum on each sample for the complete signal. Each sample would in this case have this value when it's reconstructed using the first 3 overtones ($A$=amplitude, $P$=phase):

$$A_0\cos(x+P_0)+A_1\cos(x+P_1)+A_2\cos(x+P_2)$$

Does anybody know if there is a smarter way so that it's no need to calculate the phase and amplitude before the signal is reconstructed?
Thanks

Comment: How about taking IFFT after setting the overtones after the $N$th one to zero?

Comment: Interesting idea! Do you know if I need to leave the conjugates unchanged or can I just whipe everything after the Nth overtone?

Comment: If we use complex numbers in the FFT it is not for nothing. Let $X(k) = \text{FFT}[x(n)]$. Then look at $\text{FFT}^{-1}[X(k) 1_{|X(k)| > C}]$ where $C$ is your threshold constant, for example $\frac{\max_k |X(k)|}{10}$.